# Quick Sight Incremental Refresh Not working

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, amazon-quicksight

I have a MySQL Aurora table that gets feeds every minute and have build a QS report with only last 2 days data with a custom SQL.

I setup a Incremental refresh via Quicksight to refresh every 15 minutes with a window size of 1 Hour, the problem is data is not get refreshed except if I change to 6 hours. This table contains only additions and no modifications.

Thanks
Musthafa

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the Date Column you used for the incremental refresh has the time in UTC (or in a date format containing the timezone) of when the new data arrived.

Comment: I do have the date column with date time